# XML Validation Error Mobilefirst App Authenticity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

I have a server which has been upgraded from IBM Worklight 6.0 to IBM Mobilefirst 6.3

The server is currently running older versions of my mobile application, which do not have AppAuthenticity enabled.

When I uploaded the newer version of Application, AppAuthenticity option became enabled ONLY for one (windows) environment, while others stayed disabled.

After a restart, Windows Environment version became like others, while iPAD environment started giving option to change the AppAuthenticity.

I listed the application through WLADM CLI, and it gave me below error:

> XML validation error, reading from 
>   https://URL/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/worklight/applications/MYAPPS?locale=en_US:
>   cvc-complex-type.4:  Attribute 'downloadLink' must appear on element
>   'applicationEnvironmentDataAccess'.

Please note, the application if ran alone on other server is working fine with same Application-descriptor and WAR file, only when Old and new versions are uploaded on same server, this problem comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Idan said, the 6.0 and 6.3 app can not be handled together, since I only wanted to enable the App Authenticity in the newer version, what I did as a workaround was to connect via WLADM tool and disable the App Authenticity for Older Versions via command line.

Below are the commands one needs to use:

```
\Worklight\shortcuts>wladm --url=https://server.url/wladmin --user=admin --passwordfile=password.properties
```

to verify the application's current Authenticity :

```
app version %CONTEXT% %APP_NAME% %Environment_Name% %versionCode% get authenticitycheckrule
```

To Disable

```
app version %CONTEXT% %APP_NAME% %Environment_Name% %versionCode% set authenticitycheckrule DISABLED
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying your server has a single .war file with 2 apps on it, one from 6.0 and one from 6.3?

There are very different Application Authenticity Protection implementations in 6.0 and 6.3. These cannot co-exist in the *same* single .war file.

You need to deploy to your application server 2 .war files - one for handling the 6.0 app and another for handling the 6.3 app.

Relevant user documentation can be read here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_in_production_env.html